# A variable won't display

Tags: php, mysql

I have code that runs a query on the database and returns some data and displays it.
All very simple. I've tested the query and it work's perfectly.

So somewhere between the query being executed and me displaying the data, it's not working.

```
$q = "SELECT u.username, r.position, r.score, r.winner, t.team FROM ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_ROUNDS." r
                      LEFT JOIN ".TBL_USERS." u ON u.id = r.winner
                      LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TOUR_PLAYERS." pl ON pl.userid = r.winner
                      LEFT JOIN ".TBL_FOOT_TEAMS." t ON t.id = pl.team
                      WHERE r.tourid = '$tour_id' && r.round = '$i' ORDER BY r.position";
                $result = $database->query($q);
                ?>
                <div class="vertical-holder">
                    <div class="vertical-header"><p><?php echo $roundName[$i]; ?></p></div>
                    <?php
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        extract($row);
                        if($k&1){
                            ?>
                            <div class="horizontal-holder<?php echo $j; ?>">
                                <div class="white-holder">
                                    <div class="player-holder">
                                        <?php
                                        if($winner == 0){
                                            echo "<p>TBC</p>";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo "<p><a href='/profile.php?id=$winner'>$username</a><br />$team</p>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="score-holder">
                                        <?php 
                                        if($score == NULL){
                                            echo "<p>-</p>";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            echo "<p>$score</p>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                        }
```

That's the snippet of code that's (what I believe to be) relevant.

The score is showing as '-' all the time even when a score is present.

The rest of the returned data shows no problem.

Can anyone see why the score variable isn't showing?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you want to check if the score is higher then -1 and in that case just display a dash? Also, is your field in the db named exactly score?

Comment: It's named exactly score and can be NULL. I'm changing the question to what it was originally.

Comment: @Luke sounds good :) now, what happens in your function extract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
    if($score == NULL){
        echo "<p>-</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>$score</p>";
    }
?>
```

you got it wrong. if the value in the database is null, $score will not be null, it will be the string "null". so try

```
<?php 
    if(strtoupper($score) === "NULL"){
        echo "<p>-</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>$score</p>";
    }
?>
```

:)

alternatively you can create some utility function that changes a variable:

```
function nullify(&$data) {
    if(strtoupper($data) === "NULL") {
        $data = NULL;
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
nullify($score);
```

if $score should be set to null, it will be null after the call. then you can keep your logic the way it is ^^

Comment: Also, you might find [MySQLi STMTs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) helpful. They allow you to bind parameters and results of queries to variables and probably achieve what you're doing with `extract` in a slightly more structured way. Just a suggestion though..

Comment: That strtoupper worked! Ideal, never come across that. So if you extract data from the db that is NULL, it comes out as 'null'? Interesting!

Comment: yup.. means that if you want to be able to both store the string value "null" in the database, **and** let the field be able to be null, you'll have to use some special strategy. but, if it's easy to determine null values, the nullify strategy works really well! maybe you could put that in your extract-function? then values in php will be null instead of "null". more semantic and easier to code with.

Comment: I think I'll add the nullify function you provided. Saves all this hassle of trying to find a workaround!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what `$score` contains, but it seems to me that you could write your test like:

```
if($score < -1){ // or $score <= -1
    echo "<p>-</p>";
}
else{
    echo "<p>$score</p>";
}
```

Comment: in this case it may be <= instead of < if($score <= -1){ echo "<p>-</p>"; }

Comment: @Fabian: yes it may, that's why I put it in comment line.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Next time I'll read more carefully.